# SVG.js: Animate matrix via morph() method

Tags: javascript, svg, svg.js

I would like to animate a transform matrix using SVG.js. There is a method listed,
**matrix.morph()**, that is intended to do this. I can't make this happen.

Below is an example that attempts to apply this method, but it does not do anything. Could someone please show me how to animate a transform matrix using SVG.js. Thanks.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>SVG.js - Rect Animate Matrix Morph</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//svgDiscovery.com/SVG.js/svg.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body style='padding:10px;font-family:arial;'>
<center>
<h4>SVG.js - Rect Animate Animate Matrix Morph</h4>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<div id="svgDiv" style='background-color:lightgreen;width:400px;height:400px;'></div>
</td>
</tr></table>
<script>
    var mySVG = SVG('svgDiv').size(400, 400);
    var myRect = mySVG.rect(100,100).attr({x:150,y:150,id:'myRect',fill: '#f00','stroke-width':3,stroke:'black'});
    var myRectMatrix = new SVG.Matrix
    var myRectMatrixMorph=myRectMatrix.morph(1,2,3,4,5,6)
    console.log(myRectMatrixMorph.toString())

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To animate the transformation of an element you do it the same way as setting a transform on the element - with the `transform()` method.
You dont need to touch the morph methods yourself when animating.

Try:

```
el.animate().transform({rotation:25})
// or with matrix
el.animate().transform({a:1, b:0, c:0 .... })
// or with SVG.Matrix
el.animate().transform(new SVG.Matrix(1,0,0 ....))
```

The morph method is only for the case you want a matrix at a specific position. Like:

```
var m1 = new SVG.Matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)
var m2 = new SVG.Matrix(2,0,0,2,0,0)
m1.morph(m2)
m1.at(0.5) // returns matrix (1.5,0,0,1.5,0,0)
```